# How to update Minecraft on the Xbox One

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How can I update Minecraft on the Xbox One?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What have you tried? I suppose that there is a big green update button to update on Xbox. Try looking in some sort of updates tab

Comment: You don't. The Xbox One updates its games automatically. If that doesn't happen, then you should probably connect the Xbox to the internet. If it's already connected to the internet, then there was no update to download.

Comment: @Nolonar That seems like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Xbox One updates its games automatically, and does not offer any way to do so manually. Naturally, in order to update games, the Xbox One needs to be connected to the internet.

If it still doesn't install updates despite being connected to the internet, then there was no update to install.

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox 1 updates pretty slowly. So just wait and it will eventually get it. But it will always be behind on the latest update.